# Qt and Shockwave player

Tags: qt, flash

I am writing an app which opens a variety of presentation type format files. The files often contain embedded Flash player (swf) files. I can extract these and drop them into Google Chrome and they play fine. However I want to open these in my UI. Is there a UI wigdet/library that can be used to play swf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use WebKit. You can have a `QWebView` containing html with a flash object and WebKit's flash plugin will do the rest. You can use `<embed>` to embed the flash player in a html file :

```
webView = new QWebView(this);
QWebSettings *settings = webView->settings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
webView->load(QUrl("qrc:/Path/To/pa"));

web->show();
```

html file :

```
<object ...>
<param value='1.swf'>
<embed src='1.swf'></embed>
</param>
</object>
```

You can  also use `setHtml` to set the html containing the embedded swf to the web view :

```
webView->setHtml(HtmlString);
```